# how to access method in one component from other independent component in angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I have multiple method in one component, I want to use some method of first component in second component. How to access them.
Need help.

Comment: Hi manu jaggi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you show us what you've tried so far, and describe in what way it is not working? Remember, on this site you are encouraged to [edit] and re-edit your question to improve it as much as possible.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Answer (score 3):

1:very easy through making method "Static"
in component one "comp1" make method

```
 static methodcomp1()
{
// defination
}
```

in component second "comp2" call it in any method by [ import comp1 here

```
comp1.methodcomp1();
```

2: using view child http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/01/23/angular2-viewchildren-contentchildren-difference-viewproviders/

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create some reusable code it is better to put such logic to Service, and inject to both components, so will able to use the same method of your service. But if that methods is something what helps you to control partials, I mean your components do similar logic, you can create `BaseComponentClass` and inherit your two components classes from it (TypeScript and ES6 help us with that).